# nativescript app- cannot read propert of getCookie null

Tags: angular, nativescript, typescript1.8

am developing nativescript app with angular2 and typescript. while buliding the app it success fully built but http calls fails to execute. am using @angular:"2.0.0" and nativescript-angular: "0.6.0". below included my error log. anyone please help me. Thanks in advance

```
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onClick failed

Error: Error in login/login.html:7:77 caused by: Cannot read property 
'getCookie' of null
File:     
"/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js, line: 9688, column: 20


StackTrace: 
Frame: function:'DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext',file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js', line: 9688, column: 21
Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js', line: 9701, column: 27
Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/renderer.js', line: 221, column: 26
Frame: function:'ZoneDelegate.invoke', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js', line: 190, column: 28
Frame: function:'NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke', file:'/data/data/o
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",
"email-validator": "1.0.4",
"everlive-sdk": "1.7.1",
"nativescript-angular": "0.6.0",
"nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "1.0.1",
"nativescript-social-share": "1.3.0",
"nativescript-unit-test-runner": "^0.3.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"tns-core-modules": "2.2.1"
},

"devDependencies": {
"zone.js": "^0.6.21",
"babel-traverse": "6.8.0",
"babel-types": "6.8.1",
"babylon": "6.8.0",
"codelyzer": "0.0.28",
"filewalker": "0.1.2",
"jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
"karma": "^1.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-nativescript-launcher": "^0.4.0",
"lazy": "1.0.11",
"nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
"tslint": "^3.14.0",
"typescript": "^1.8.10"
}
```

Login.html

```
<StackLayout>
<Image src="res://logo_login" stretch="none" 
horizontalAlignment="center"></Image>

<TextField hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email"  
[(ngModel)]="user.email"
autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
<TextField hint="Password" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="user.password"> 
</TextField>
```

Comment: You should post your login.html code, as  that's where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possible that problem is same as here

> https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/305

**In short**:
Try change all "HTTP_PROVIDERS" to "NS_HTTP_PROVIDERS"